# Cannot find module 'formiojs/full'

Tags: angular, formbuilder, formio

I a implementing the [Formio angular custom component](https://gist.github.com/travist/59fa77086ec899e24992fc1508e61075)

while implementing the `app.component.js` I have used the following import, it is giving me the error.

**error:-**

> Cannot find module 'formiojs/full'.

`import { FormioForm } from 'formiojs/full';`